# asp.net mvc localization. Views are localized, embedded resources in external DLL not

Tags: asp.net, globalization

I have encountered a very strange issue with localization in ASP.NET MVC. Let me outline my projects since it is not that straight forward.

I have a TRUNK version of my website. The website uses two localization techniques. The first one is to load resources within the views from App_LocalResources. The second technique is to load resources from embedded resources in DLLs (project references).

On one view I show some lables which are localized from the view and I also load some labels via AJAX/JSON. The Action gets the localized data from an embedded resource in a referenced class project (DLL). Actually, in TRUNK, this works pretty well.

Now the Problem: I have a BRANCH which does not have a project reference to the embedded resource but a reference to a compiled DLL (copy). In the BRANCH the localization only works for the View, not for the AJAX/JSON call which simply returns the default locale.

What can be wrong? Do you have to make an settings on the DLLs if you redistribute them?!

Comment: Oh - the answer is so easy:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991289/stuck-with-localization-using-resource-files